logman trace unusable: no names or "<unknown>" everything
I have a USB device that, only on two specific computers, spontaneously disconnects and then cannot be reconnected to the same computer for a short if arbitrary timespan.
Because the device works fine on the majority of computers I have access to and I have no second computer of the two affected types, I presume it might be a hardware or driver incompatiblity.
Following advice from e.g. this Super User answer and documentation from Microsoft I wrote these two batch files to attempt to confirm or deny my suspicion with logman:
startTrace.bat
logman create trace -n usbtrace -o %SystemRoot%\Tracing\usbtrace.etl -nb 128 640 -bs 128 -ow
logman update trace -n usbtrace -p Microsoft-Windows-USB-USBXHCI (Default,HeadersBusTrace)
logman update trace -n usbtrace -p Microsoft-Windows-USB-UCX (Default,HeadersBusTrace)
logman update trace -n usbtrace -p Microsoft-Windows-USB-USBHUB3 (Default,HeadersBusTrace)
logman update trace -n usbtrace -p Microsoft-Windows-USB-USBPORT
logman update trace -n usbtrace -p Microsoft-Windows-USB-USBHUB
logman update trace -n usbtrace -p Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-IoTrace 0 2
logman start -n usbtrace

(There does not seem to be any way to look up valid/sensible arguments for -p, FWIW. The part in braces are the ETW keywords from the Microsoft article, everything else is magic. ~~)
stopTrace.bat
logman stop -n usbtrace
logman delete -n usbtrace

Then for a test run I

disconnect all other USB devices
call startTrace.bat as administrator
connect the USB device
start using the USB device
disconnect the USB device
call stopTrace.bat as administrator

Checking the created file, I find it completely unusable, because all the useful fields are empty or filled with garbage.
How do I get at least some of these fields filled with meaningful information?
(I would at least have expected the device name as seen, e.g. in the Device Manager to be mentioned somewhere in these events, but apparently... )
Here is what I get:

Provider name: one of three GUIDs, no idea how to resolve these or what to or why three
Task name: always empty
Opcode name: always empty
Id: seems to be an incrementing unsigned integral starting at 1, so particular to this logging session, nothing that could be referenced outside
Process: always "Unknown" or "Unknown (0)"
a column without any text, coloured yellow
Event name: always empty
Cpu: works as expected but does not help
ThreadId: works as expected but does not help
another column without any text, this one just white
Count: works as expected but does not help (you'd think I could find connect and disconnect by filtering for "1" but there are literally hundreds of entries with count 1)
Time (s): works as expected but does not help
Legend: grey rectangle or violet rectangle; can be clicked on to toggle the filling between colour and white; mouse-over always says "enabled", regardless of state; nothing else seems to change when toggling one of these either

Even though I know exactly when the device disconnected, because I disconnected it myself and then stopped the trace, I was unable to find the relating event in the trace.
Same for when it connected.
This does not help.
X/Y answer: Despite Microsofts wording, might this simply be the wrong tool? (This answer seems to imply so, but then why would the fields even exist, if they can never be filled?) In this case, is there another tool bundled with Windows 10+ that could (better) fulfill this task?
